# std::thread is not a member of namespace std using Eclipse Kepler MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, c++11, mingw

I'm trying to compile a simple c++ program that uses std::thread on eclipse kepler / mingw 4.8.1 and win32.  I hope to move development to linux at some point after many years on windows development.

```
#include "test.h"
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    Test::CreateInstance();

    std::thread(
        [&]()
        {
            Test::I()->Output2();
        }
    );

    Test::DestroyInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

Ignoring the purpose of test (it's a singleton that just produces some output that I will expand upon, once I get the std::thread working!)

The g++ compiler settings I've set in Eclipse are:

```
-c -fmessage-length=0  -std=c++0x -Wc++0x-compat
```

And the preprocessor symbol I have defined is:

```
__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
```

Building complains that std::thread is not a member of std:

```
    10:30:13 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -Wc++0x-compat -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
..\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\main.cpp:11:2: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
  std::thread(
  ^
```

Can someone suggest what I might be missing to get this compiling correctly?

Comment: What version of `MinGW` are you using? And don`t you have to link against `pthread` as well?

Comment: am using mingw v4.8.1.  I didn't think I was using pthreads.  I thought I was using std::thread?  Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plain MinGW cannot support `std::thread`. You will need to use a MinGW-w64 toolchain (such as those shipped with Qt 5) that has "posix" threading enabled, so that libstdc++ exposes the `<thread>`, `<mutex>` and `<future>` functionality.

You can find an installer [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/), but you can also try just replacing the whole `mingw` toolchain root folder with [one of these packages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/). You can choose 32- or 64-bit, remember to select `threads-posix` if you want to play with `std::thread` and friends. No special compiler options other than the ones you already have are needed. I do suggest using `-std=c++11` if you don't need GCC 4.6 compatibility.

Comment: It's not a problem of compiler support, the compiler does not know or care about threads. It's the standard library that is missing the implementation. See answer below for a native lightweight solution, rather than using pthread emulation on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, though I worked with Cygwin compiler instead. What I did was to define the symbol `__cplusplus` with the value `201103L` for the preprocessor. Also I'd used the flag `-std=c++11` for the compiler. This settings have to be made for All configurations (Debug & Release).

Another thing that you may check is that you have properly installed the compiler, verify your compiler instalation as explained by rubenvb.

Comment: `-std=c++11` should set `__cplusplus` accordingly. You should *never* set `__cplusplus` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

See here for a native implementation that can be added to any C++11 version of MinGW:
https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads
It is a header-only library, so you just need to include the headers in your project and you will get C++11 threads and synchronization primitives.