# C++11, GCC 4.8.1,Code::Blocks, threading, what a head ache

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11, codeblocks

**--EDIT**
If you would like to use MinGW GCC 8.4.1 and threads/mutex/futures/atomics do not download the Win32 threader version insted download the Posix version.
**--EDIT**

My installation of MinGW is as follows:
x32-4.8.1-release-win32 (as the threader) - sjlj rev 5

I have unpacked and correctly confirmed that **MinGW GCC 4.8.1 (revision 5) is installed in C:\MinGW\mingw32.**   I have set up Code Blocks to look for the latest and greatest compiler in the correct path (this I am sure of).  I can compile a normal program using **#include iostream.**  Ok now when I try and run a program using **#include thread** it gives me **"error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'".**

*Now here is what I have done and what I have tried:*

I am **following a sort of template or tutorial here at** [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/?kw=thread).
I have the code exactly as it is presented on the webpage (towards the bottom).
I have tried, in Code Blocks, to use Compiler flags **"Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO language standard -std=c++11".**

I have also tried the flag **"Have g++ follow the coming C++0x ISO language standard -std=c++0x"**

I have tried both at the same time and one at a time, no mas.
I have also tried those commands **manually**.

Another command I tried manually was **-std=gnu++11** which was recommended in the thread header.

---

**--EDIT**
It seems like **__cplusplus** is < 201103L which is stated (or rather defined) in the thread header. 
This only happens when I manually use -std=c++11, for some reason C::B removes it if it was manually stated so I must use a check box to use this flag...
**--EDIT**

My compiler settings under the **Toolchain Executables tab** are as follows:

C compiler: **i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.1.exe**

C++ compiler: **i686-w64-mingw32-c++.exe**

Linker for dynamic: **i686-w64-mingw32-c++.exe**

Linker for static: **ar.exe**

Debbuger: **GDB/CDB debugger: default**

Resource compiler: **windres.exe**

Make Program: **mingw32-make.exe**

I have tried using other executables in the bin folder and still no luck...
I'm starting to wonder if GCC supports C++11 or threading !?

Has anyone been able to get threads to work with MinGW GCC, Code blocks or in general?
If so how did you do it? Any links that might help? Any advice?

P.S. I know there are other ways of threading like posix or other SDK's like SFML (I have successfully tried threading with this).  But I want to use GCC threading and I'm quite baffled as to why it is so hard to do seeing as all the necessary files are there...

**--EDIT**
I have found that when I manually compile the program outside of Code Blocks I still get the same errors, whether I use g++ c++ or i686-w64-mingw32-g++/c++

here is the command I run to build the files:

> C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin>g++.exe -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -o0 -g3
>   -Wall -c -fmes sage-length=0 -std=c++11 -Wc++11-compat -o obj\Debug\main.o "F:\C Projects\Code Blocks\thread\main.cpp"

still returns error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'

Could this be a bad build? I will try other revisions...
**--EDIT**

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18913685/341970) you need a 64 bit version of the Mingw toolchain. (I have never tried it myself.)

Comment: I am using the correct MinGW how ever instead of posix threading I am using Win32 threading (running the GCC -v command confirms that Win32 is set up for threading). I will try downloading the posix version and see if that works, however, I did want this to be more a win32 threading application. Thank you!

Comment: Ali, thank you I have tried your articles help but it still is not working for me :(   check out my build log compile flags, I tried to match them as close as possible with fishfoods: **i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall  -g  -std=c++11 -c -Wc++11-compat -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__    -c "F:\C Projects\Code Blocks\thread\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o**

Comment: What error do you get? The same one as you state in the title? Could you try adding -pthread to the compiler flags? (Works on Linux, I have no idea what -pthread does on Windows.) If you still get the same error then the most likely explanation is that something is messed up on your machine and you are including the wrong header files. I know it doesn't help you much... Sorry. :(

Comment: Here are the flags with -pthread but because I use win32 as the threader this will fail and has: **i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall  -g  -std=c++11 -c -std=gnu++11 -pthread -Wc++11-compat -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__    -c "F:\C Projects\Code Blocks\thread\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o**
error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'   Please note I know it says i686...g++.exe but I try all the c++ compilers in the directory i.e. i've tried this with g++.exe c++.exe (it came with more than one c++ compiler apparently).

Comment: I don't understand why **-wall** and **-g** are always called even if I have no compile flags selected in C::B, could these be getting in the way of building properly? Currently I also just did a fresh install of C::B so there is nothing it should be looking for other than in the directory I made **C:\MinGW\mingw32**

Comment: I know for sure that pthreads have been ported to Windows. What -pthread does on Windows, well, that is a different story. The -wall flag turns on all warnings, that is good practice, and -g is to generate debug information. These flags are irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: In any case, the error message says that somehow the compiler is looking at a wrong header file. Unfortunately, I cannot help you with that, I am really sorry.

Answer (score 3):

probably to late for an answere, but here is what worked for me:

**1.** Get x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8-stdthread-win64_rubenvb.7z from:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-experimental-stdthread/

**2.** Setup a new compiler in codeblocks with

- x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.1.exe
- x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
- x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
- ar.exe
- windres.exe
- mingw32-make.exe

**3.** Set the new compiler for your project

- Right click in your project -> build options
- Select the new compiler
- Under compiler falgs check -std=c++0x and -std=c++11
- Under Other options set -std=gnu++11

**4.** Have fun with c++11 concurrency

Hope that works for you also, as an alternative you can just use visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant GCC 4.8.1 - the answer is yes, it supports a set of C++11 features including partial multi-threading support. Please visit http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html to see supported set.

Comment: Yes, I did mean 4.8.1 thank you it's been a long day ;)    That's great that it supports it but then why am I having such trouble getting this thing to build?

Answer (score 0):

gcc 4.8.1 is C++11 feature complete. I cannot speak to the Windows implementation but certainly on Linux and OS X it works as advertised, including all the concurrency functionality. I just `#include <thread>` and call `g++ -std=gnu++11` and it works. Here's a minimal piece of code that compiles just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mx;
int i;

void thrfunc();

int main(void)
{
   i=0;
   std::thread          thr1(thrfunc),thr2(thrfunc);

   thr1.join();
   thr2.join();

   return 0;
}

void thrfunc()
{
   mx.lock();
   i++;
   std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " i: " << i << std::endl;
   mx.unlock();
}
```

Comment: David, That code does not compile correctly either! It throws errors at me when I try and build it. when I edit the code like this its fine: (note I can keep the includes but any functions classes or methods from those files will not work)           '#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

//std::mutex mx;
int i;

void thrfunc();

int main(void)
{
   i=0;
   //std::thread          thr1(thrfunc),thr2(thrfunc);

   //thr1.join();
   //thr2.join();
   thrfunc();
   return 0;
}

void thrfunc()
{
   //mx.lock();
   i++;
   std::cout << " i: " << i << std::endl;
   //mx.unlock();
}'

Comment: I get the **error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type. **  I have noticed when I manually enter **-std=c++11** for **compiler flags,** after I build the program I go back to **compiler flags** and it isn't there any more.  It is the only **compiler flag** that does this...

Comment: Then I think it would be safe to say that either a) your compiler implementation is not truly 4.8.1 b) it is broken, or c) you are not passing it some flags it expects. Under Linux the -pthread compiler flag needs to be passed so there may be an analogous problem. If you are using the current trunk version of MinGW you will need to ensure that it does in fact have a thread model associated with it (both Mac and Linux gcc use POSIX threads by default, for example.)

Comment: IIRC the similar option for `-pthread` on windows is `-mthread`, but its abscence should hide `std::mutex`, just produce linker errors or broken code.

Comment: **Daniel,** I have tried -pthread (with -std=c++11) still throws the same error. I have tried -mthread (with -std=c++11) and it did not recognize it. maybe -wthread?         **David,** the thread model associated with it is Win32 (I can see this with a gcc -v).  I'd rather keep it win32 unless I absolutely must use posix.  I too wonder if there is compiler flags that I am missing, which sounds like the true problem.  **Thanks again for your help, everyone!**

Comment: If it helps here is the output of the build with some of the flags I've tried (still has not worked :( ) :  **i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall  -g  -std=c++11 -pthread    -c "F:\C Projects\Code Blocks\thread\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, I installed the lates MinGW-Builds

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/mingw-builds-install/
and set my toolchain executables to:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.1.exe
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
ar.exe
windres.exe
mingw32-make.exe
```

I hope this helps.