# How to configure Eclipse to use a particular MinGW toolchain

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, eclipse-cdt

So I spent all day trying to get c++ threads to work with eclipse Kepler and mingw.   I have tried adding the -std=c++11 flag, -lpthread flag, another flag and even added a symbol to the table **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X**. My latest attempt at getting threads to work is to follow this advice 
[std::thread is not a member of namespace std using Eclipse Kepler MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913542/stdthread-is-not-a-member-of-namespace-std-using-eclipse-kepler-mingw)

which says:

> Plain MinGW cannot support std::thread. You will need to use a
>   MinGW-w64 toolchain (such as those shipped with Qt 5) that has "posix"
>   threading enabled, so that libstdc++ exposes the thread, mutex and
>   future functionality. You can find an installer here.

Now I have a folder called: 
C:\Program Files\mingw-builds\x64-4.8.1-posix-seh-rev5
How do I get this to work with eclipse so I can use threading? Do I have to replace something in my mingw file or somehow link this to eclipse? I have no clue where to even begin.LET ALONE if this is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_installed_MinGW_toolchain_on_my_PC_but_Eclipse_won.27t_find_it.)

I think it is along the lines of what you want to do because basically you need to show eclipse a different version of MinGW. It looks like you'll need to set the PATH variable correctly so eclipse can find the new version.