# Thread was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am learning concurrent programing with c++ and I have a problem. I get en error:

> "thread was not declared in this scope error"

with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void function1(){
    cout << "Beauty is only skin deep" << endl;
}

int main(){
    thread t1(function1);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using CodeBlock and I have enabled this option in compiler settings:
"Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]"

I am using C++11 a lot and this is only thing that doesn't work. How to fix that ?

My operating system is Windows XP and compiler is GNU GCC

EDIT:

my PATH: "D:\Aplikacje\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Dane aplikacji\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\Aplikacje\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin;D:\Aplikacje\Borland\CBUILD~1\Projects\Bpl;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32\wbem;C:\PROGRAM FILES\QUICKTIME\QTSYSTEM;%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\xampp\mysql\lib;D:\aplikacje\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;D:\Aplikacje\MATLAB\R2011a\runtime\win32;D:\Aplikacje\MATLAB\R2011a\bin"

EDIT2: Full compiler output:

"||=== ewghm, Debug ===|
C:\Documents and Settings\KM\Pulpit\PROGRAMY\ewghm\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|

C:\Documents and Settings\KM\Pulpit\PROGRAMY\ewghm\main.cpp|10|error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope|

C:\Documents and Settings\KM\Pulpit\PROGRAMY\ewghm\main.cpp|10|error: expected ';' before 't1'|

||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
"

Comment: As a side note: Don't use `using namespace std;`. As for your question you should specify exactly which toolchain version you are using, to find an appropriate answer.

Comment: Provide full output of the compiler log. You had also to tell what compiler and OS you are using. It seems it is windows, so it might be mingw, but why should we be an extrasensory? Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913542/stdthread-is-not-a-member-of-namespace-std-using-eclipse-kepler-mingw)?

Comment: try TDM-GCC(http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net ) afaik normal mingw doesn't support therads due to legal reasons